# streaming a "favorite/like" of a user on soundcloud not working

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

Why is this not working? I have sourced how to do this from [here](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/sdks#javascript)

I have now edited this because the `sound.play` works but the `sound.pause` doesn't and I don't know why?

Is it because of duplicate function names?

```
    if ($(this).attr('src') == 'Play.png') {
    SC.get("/users/user/favorites", function (track) {
        SC.get("/users/user/favorites", function (tracks) {
            SC.stream("/tracks/" + tracks[0].id, function (sound) {
                sound.play();
            });
        });
    });

    $("#swap").attr('src', "../Pause.png");
} else {
    SC.get("/users/user/favorites", function (track) {
        SC.get("/users/user/favorites", function (tracks) {
            SC.stream("/tracks/" + tracks[0].id, function (sound) {
                sound.pause();
            });
        });
    });


    $("#swap").attr('src', "Play.png");
}
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SC.stream()` method takes a path to a single resource, not a list/array. Try this:

```
SC.get("/users/[user]/favorites", function(tracks){
  SC.stream("/tracks/"+tracks[0].id, function(sound){
    sound.play();
  });
});
```

**Edit**:

To answer your updated question, I've updated your code:

```
window.sound = null;
$('#swap').on('click', function(e){
  if ($(this).attr('src') == 'Play.png') {
    if (!sound) {
      SC.get("/users/user/favorites", function (tracks) {
        SC.stream("/tracks/" + tracks[0].id, function (sound) {
          window.sound = sound;
          sound.play();
        });
      });
    } else { sound.play() }
    $(this).attr('src', "Pause.png");
  } else {
    sound.pause();
    $(this).attr('src', "Play.png");
  }
});
```

Comment: I then have an if statement for the `sound.pause` which doesn't seem to work.

Check updated answer

Comment: Thank you that works perfect! Do you have any idea how I could change the `tracks[0]` change to `tracks[1]` etc... once each track has finished? 

I was thinking about replacing `tracks[0]` with `tracks[song]` then creating something with the effect of

`var song = 0;
 SC.get("/users/user/favorites", function(track){
 if(/*time after click*/ === track[song].duration){
 var song = song +1;
 
 }
 });`

Comment: Can you help me with this?